# How can I simulate a USB printer to LPT on Linux?

Tags: linux, printing, lpt

I have an Intermec printer connected on an USB port to my computer, the computer doesn't have a parallel port.

I want to send some raw commands to the printer, the printer interprets the file send as commands only if it is send on the parallel port (LPT). At the momment, the printer connected on USB will print the commands as text on the paper.

In Windows this can be achieved by sharing the printer on the network and then using the following:

> NET USE LPT1: \127.0.0.1\Printer /PERSISTENT:YES

Can I do the same in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer of Michał Sacharewicz is perfectly correct for your problem/question, you should be looking at the underlying problem.

I have never heard of a printer who treats input from the USB-port differently from input from its LPT-port. If it does that then Linux itself could not send commands to the printer via the drivers.

So are you sure the printer is treating them differently?

How are you printing your test-file (with commands) to the printer? If the file goes through a driver it gets mangled and you only get text. You should print it as RAW-file. For example with `lp` you can try to use `lp -o raw filename`.

Comment: the lp -o raw command worked seamless

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't symlink be a roughly adequate linux solution? `ln -s /dev/us* /dev/lp0`.

But I'm afraid that neither windows nor linux solution would work for you. After all, **you'll still be sending commands to the USB port**, regardless of how you represent it in your OS internally.

You may have better luck with [USB to LPT converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB%20to%20LPT).